# React-admin tab name translate

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am using React-admin and following the demo that they give out. So far everything is working except for the Tab name/title translation. I have done the translation correctly because other **components** that have **label** attribute works fine with the translation.

Translations are getting from `en.js` file and added to `app.js` according to the **react-admin** documentation.

Here is my code :

```
class TabbedDatagrid extends React.Component {
  tabs = [
      { id: 'countries', name: 'root.countries.title' },
      { id: 'languages', name: 'root.languages.title' },
  ];
  state = {  countries: [], languages: [] };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
      if (props.ids !== state[props.filterValues.status]) {
          return { ...state, [props.filterValues.status]: props.ids };
      }
      return null;

  }

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
      const { filterValues, setFilters } = this.props;
      setFilters({ ...filterValues, status: value });
  };

  render() {
      const { classes, filterValues, ...props } = this.props;
      return (
          <Fragment>
              <Tabs
                  fullWidth
                  centered
                  value={filterValues.status}
                  indicatorColor="primary"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}

              >
                  {this.tabs.map(choice => (
                      <Tab
                          key={choice.id}
                          label={choice.name}
                          value={choice.id}
                      />

                  ))}
              </Tabs>
              <Divider />
              <Responsive
                  small={<SimpleList primaryText={record => record.title} />}
                  medium={
                      <div>                           
                          {filterValues.status === 'countries' && (
                                <Datagrid hover={false}
                                   {...props}
                                   ids={this.state['countries']}
                                   >
                                    <TextField source="id" />
                                    <TextField source="name"  label="root.countries.fields.name"/>
                                </Datagrid>
                                )}
                            {filterValues.status === 'languages' && (

                           <Datagrid hover={false}

                              {...props}

                              ids={this.state['languages']}

                              >

                               <TextField source="id" />

                              <TextField source="name"  label="root.languages.fields.name"/>

                           </Datagrid>
                       )}
                      </div>

                  }

              />

          </Fragment>

      );

  }

}
```

The translations seems to work everywhere else but the `Tab` label, What I get instead of the Title is uppercase string of this `root.countries.title`.

Is there a workaround or how to fix this issue?

Comment: translations are getting from a  en.js file which incorporated into the app.js file , its not getting values from the state

Answer (score 1):

You probably used `<Tab/>` 'directly' from `material-ui`.

You need to use (create) 'enhanced version' (using `translate` prop) of this component.

Take inspiration from [menu](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/1c13a20cac4eba7cc58d6990a48cc07b60bb1cb9/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/layout/Menu.js) or other translatable components.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your translations to your App.js as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import frenchMessages from 'ra-language-french';
import englishMessages from 'ra-language-english';

const messages = {
    fr: { component:{label:'test'},...frenchMessages },
    en: { component:{label:'test'},...englishMessages },,
}
const i18nProvider = locale => messages[locale];

const App = () => (
    <Admin locale="en" i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

than when you want to use translations inside a component, you need to connect it to the react-admin's translate function as follows :

```
import { TextInput, translate } from 'react-admin';

const translatedComponent = ({translate, ...props}) => {
return <TextInput label={translate('component.label')} />
}

export default translate(translatedComponent);
```

**it is important to connect the component with translate and to get the translate function from props to get the translation work.**